# How can I remove all default installed games?

Tags: uninstall, games

I want to remove all the games that are installed by default.

How can I do it all at once?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-games-common gbrainy && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 39):

I received a "Virtual packages like 'gnome-games-common' can't be removed" whenever I tried Reda Lazri's solution on 12.04 LTS; ended up using:

```
sudo apt-get purge aisleriot gnome-sudoku mahjongg ace-of-penguins gnomine gbrainy gnome-mines
```

Comment: As of 14.04.1 the following works: `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-mahjongg gnomine gnome-sudoku aisleriot`

Comment: 16.04.1 works for: `sudo apt-get purge aisleriot gnome-sudoku` also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/433609/how-can-i-list-all-applications-installed-in-my-system to get a bunch of other things removed too.

Comment: Also `sudo apt purge gnome-mines` (18.04).

Answer (score 29):

For Ubuntu 16.10 the following command should remove all default games:

```bsh
sudo apt remove aisleriot gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-sudoku
```

Comment: This works fine for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS version.

Comment: This works well on Ubuntu 20.01 LTS version as well.

Answer (score 8):

install synaptic package manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
synaptic
```

Choose menu item .. Settings > filters
In the lower left of the window click "New". Enter a name at the top left. On the right side
click "Deselect All", then click "Installed" to check only that box. Now click on the Section
tab and select the "Include selected sections only" radio button. In the list above ctrl+click
to include the following from the list:
  games, multiuniverse/games, universe/games. Press OK to exit the window and save your filter.

Click Custom Filters at the lower left and you should have a new entry with the name you choose
in the list above. Click that to see a list of all games that are installed. On the right top
pane click the button in the first column then click "mark for removal". Mark for complete removal
to also remove any settings. Finally, use the √ along the top of the interface to apply
the removal.

- see synaptic menu .. Help[F1] > Custom Filters

Comment: Why should they install synaptic package manager to do this?

Comment: I like synaptic. I find it can do much more much faster than I. If you don't want synaptic simplest way is open software center, click "Installed" along the top, then along the left click the games tab to see what games your unbuntu has. Then click on each item in turn and then the "Remove" button on the left.

Answer (score 3):

try below commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge aisleriot gnome-sudoku mahjongg ace-of-penguins gnomine gbrainy

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-mahjongg

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-mines
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following line to remove all pre-installed games in Debian 9.9 (with gnome 3):

```bsh
sudo apt purge aisleriot gnome-sudoku mahjongg ace-of-penguins gnomine gbrainy gnome-sushi gnome-taquin gnome-tetravex  gnome-robots gnome-chess lightsoff swell-foop quadrapassel && sudo apt autoremove
```