# How may I clean ALL the cruft from 12.04?

Tags: uninstall, games

I do not want any games. I do not want any AV-related stuff (no music, no videos, no photos, ... no entertainment at all).  I do not want the LibreOffice package(s).  I am thinking about just installing the server edition, but it is a dual boot machine and wubi was a very convenient way to get it going.

Comment: Sorry if I don't get you, but could you be more specific? You want to delete existing music, vids, games, etc.? And/Or you don't want to be able to transfer/install music, vids, games, etc.? Would help us understand what you're asking a li'l better.

Comment: I would like a "minimal" installation of 12.04.  No games, no audio features, no video features, ... basically not much more than a gui and terminal access.  (I could even live nicely without the gui but sometimes it comes in handy.)

Comment: I have been going through using apt-cache pkgnames, locating "suspects" and running apt-get purge libreoffice* (for example).  But is there a way to remove a whole class of apps?

Comment: About the games thing, did you take a look at [How can I remove all default installed games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32228/how-can-i-remove-all-default-installed-games)

Comment: That helps ... but is there a way to find the names of the game packages (for example)?  Re. the video stuff, I thought about doing apt-get purge *video* but am concerned that it might be a bit heavy handed. I don't want to render the installation totally unusable!

Comment: How about `apropos`? Running `apropos game` would show you all package names which have the word "game" in their description, and you can get creative and try finding clubbed stuff like that.. Just a thought..

Comment: switch to archlinux

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar attitude to yours and have two ways for solving your problems, both used by me with success:

1. Remove unnecessary packages, leaving only those that you deem necessary. Read [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2651015&postcount=1). It's quite long, a bit complicated and I remember experiencing problems (which taught me a lot and were well worth the trouble
2. Get [Ubuntu MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and install your system from scratch (not as scratch as [linuxfromscratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)) and build up from there. I did it several times, it's not at all difficult and taught me a lot about dependencies between packages. I'm not sure whether you can marry that approach with wubi, though (didn't check, have no idea).

Answer (score 0):

It is not very hard or difficult to do from within Ubuntu Software Center. There is an 'installed' option inside USC and all you need to do is this for anything you need removed.

[image]

The games section should have just 4 or 5 options. Office is there too and has only 5 options. Same also for the audio and video option. This also removes the need to know what packages they are but for future usage you can see the package name when you click 'more info'.

So all in all the manual work to do this is not that difficult if you want to keep gnome/unity that is. Besides that: this is almost fool proof; using apt-get remove you can use wildcards yes, but those can remove more than what you would expect.

Comment: For bulk removal, you may find the older and less pretty `synaptic` GUI more efficient.

Comment: Yes but synaptic might be considered crud by TS ;)