# How to get a list of applications installed in Ubuntu dash?

Tags: 14.04, customization, application-switcher

In Gnome, we have applications grouped up based on their type (like - games, accessories, et al). But in Unity, we need to manually type in the Unity to get the App.

Is there any keyword/utility to display the applications in GUI?

Ubuntu Version : 14.04
Hardware : Dell Inspiron 3437

Comment: Mostly Found at `/usr/share/applications`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open Dash, click on the applications icon (at the bottom of Dash)

[image]

- The first row shows most recent, below are installed applications
- Click on "See more results" to see all installed applications
- Scroll up/down to see them all

To Filter the applications by category; in the right top: `Filter Results`

[image]

Comment: Cool. The answer is awesome. Now I am able to list down the installed apps.

Comment: Perfect, If you are not afraid of running a script, here is another option to get a categorized list: http://askubuntu.com/questions/490139/list-installed-applications-grouped-by-type/490398#490398. (But non-GUI :) )

Comment: This doesn't work. I open dash, click "see more results" and chrome doesn't show up, even though Chrome is most certainly installed.

Comment: @ScottF If so, it's an issue with Chrome, not with the answer :/

Answer (score 4):

Easy way: press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open the Applications with also view   group type at left.

[image]

Comment: Filter will only show up if you used it the last time in Dash, else Dash will appear without :)