# How do you find and use programs that have been installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

I recently installed a program using the terminal command `sudo apt-get install`, and I want to locate and use it, and delete it. (I only did it as a test and had no actual use for the file). Where can I locate the program now?

Comment: to list applications http://askubuntu.com/questions/518287/how-to-get-a-list-of-applications-installed-in-ubuntu-dash/518295#518295

Comment: Most applications are not "a file", but a combination of files, binaries, libraries, settings etc, spread over different (conventional) directories. To list installed applications, also (since you mentioned command-line as a tag) http://askubuntu.com/a/490398/72216

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To locate it it, use the following command :

```
dpkg -L package_name
```

Alternatively, you can search it in Unity by pressing the launcher and typing the name of the application or package you installed.
To run it as a normal user, open the terminal and type in the **application name**, that is, the command of the application. As an example, to run rhythmbox music player, you just opn the terminal and type in ***rhythmbox***, and it will open.

To uninstall an application, you need aministrative priviledges, hence the need to use sudo in a command line. In uninstalling, open the terminal and type in

> sudo apt-get remove application_name

and the applicaton will be removed. To remove everything that was added to the machine, including the installation folders and cache files, use :

> sudo apt-get purge application_name

Comment: And how can I use it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the path of a  binary you can use

`which <your_binary_file>`

for e.g.

```
[guru@guru-pc:~]$which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

You can use `dpkg -L package_name` to find the location of all the files related with that package.

From `man dpkg`

```
-L, --listfiles package-name...
                  List files installed to your system from package-name.
```

But if you want to remove any package you should use

```
 sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install programName
```

You can remove it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove programName
```

That will remove the application (but might keep a few configuration files. If you want to completely remove it, use `purge` instead of `remove`).

If you want to manually delete the files that it downloaded, or if you just want to know "where" its files got installed, I believe you can do `dpkg -L programName`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Synaptics Package Manager. To install it, run

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

in a command line.

You should be able to find your package here.

Comment: Perhaps consider adding to your answer how one could use synaptic to remove an unwanted package.?